# Filtering Pane, ASP MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, filtering

My plan is to create a a two-pane page using ASP MVC 3. The left pane should be a small filter pane and the right the main content, showing a list of objects (say products).

Initially all products will be shown since no filter is applied. When selecting "only red", only red products are shown in the list. When further selecting a price range, only products in that price range will be shown.

Functionally the plan is to implement the filtering pane as a treeview with checkboxes (to be able to drill down to more and more specific filtering options), graphically it will probably be enhanced in some way to improve usability.

What is the best way to implement the coupling between the filter pane and the main list? Everything should work server side, but should of course use javascript (jQuery) when possible for direct feedback.

The simplest way is probably to make it closely coupled solution, calling a specific Asp MVC action using a custom-built javascript (with fallback to a form post). Doable enough, sure, but how to make the solution reusable? Also it would be nice to not loose all filtering data when navigating forward and back, i suppose GET arguments is the only decent way to do that?

Are there any best practices, any guidelines or anything to base this on to make a nice modular structure for filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Victor, I recently had to solved this same problem. I'm not promising it's the best way but it's pretty clear and should even work well in case JavaScript is disabled (who even does that anymore?).

- Create a  that calls the action with all the field-selectable search options like "only red".
- To that same form, add empty, hidden value for the things not directly as fields (paging, sorting...)
- Setup your form with the excellent and very easy to use JQuery.Forms (http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) to make you form submit via JQuery (all your form values will be passed as JSON on form submit).
- Make your back/next/paging/sorting links pass their individual values via query (no-JS fallback) and use JQuery to capture their click events. The JQuery click events on those links should assign the value of the value passed by the link (page number, sort column name...) to the corresponding hidden field in the form and call submit (with thanks to Jquery.Forms will submit via AJAX).
- When you configure JQuery.Forms, you can define a callback method. In the callback method take the result (the HTML returned by your action that should contained your filtered+sorted+paged result) and replace the document (or DIV if you used a partial action + view) with that.

The result is a JQuery solution that works when JS is off. You also have very minimal JS code to write other than wiring the event handlers.

I'm not sure if it will be helpful but in MVC 3 you have access to a property called IsAjax from the view so you can do specific things to server a slightly different view when called from AJAX.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, sounds quite along the lines I was thinking - a long list of GET arguments :)    Anyway - is there any clever way to handle the server-side? Better than "Action Filter(string thisValue, string thatValue, List<bool> checkboxFiltering, int numberOfResults, int page, ...)"? Seems like the list will be long and that some more elegant solution should exist?

Comment: Actually what I've suggested would POST the arguments via a form. If you don't want to send a long list of filtering parameters, create an object with the filtering properties instead. In you action replace the parameters with the single object. Model Binding will automatically bind the posted parameters with the object's properties.

Comment: +1 and accepted - I ended up going the jQuery.Forms way. Thanks a lot. And about the arguments, GET/POST doesnt matter that much from the ASP point of view. In the end we built our solution on top of the Telerik ASP MVC Treeview components, so we used their model binding as base for simplicity.